# Feedback on sound challenge webpage.

Tags: design, recording, feedback, websites

I am creating a page on my site that is designed to get people to take a sound I recorded and manipilate it into something new. Then post the new manipulated sound for others to hear. I think it would be a good way to get feedback on your work and to describe what you did in the process to get the new sound. 
here is the link http://soundenthusiast.com/sound-challenge/

Let me know if this seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: Very cool! Count me in…

Comment: cool. Glad you like it.

Comment: coooooaoooeoooo0ooooo1

Comment: Nice. I dig it.

Comment: Feedback, get it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great idea. I lecture sound and am always looking for new ideas for assignments and practical fun things to do in class. I find that my students only practice when they have an assignment due so this will definitely be an incentive for them to understand how sounds can turned into other things. Thanks a lot for this

Comment: That is great to hear, I look forward to see others posting their versions of manipulation! 

Comment: don't forget to point them to the monthly sound design challenges i host on my website. so far, i've been able to pull together prizes for each one. i remember being a student years ago...free stuff almost always made me do things i'd normally skip out on. ;)

Comment: Good advice. I will put a link of your site on mine.

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea, I just posted my version on your page.

Comment: I just listened to it. Thats pretty cool. I didn't even think about trying the poltergeist effect. 

Answer (score 2):

Great idea. I will post soon.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea!  I am sure to give this a spin!  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of like last month's challenge on my website. People seemed to enjoy it, so I say run with it.

Here's the original posting... http://www.dynamicinterference.com/?p=218

And you can find all of the entries here... http://www.dynamicinterference.com/?p=230

Answer (score 1):

Just put mine up.